# UIWebView and Richtext files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, rtf

As far as I understand, the standard `UIWebView` is able to display local files of numerous extensions. Since I need to display formatted text in my application, I thought this method is the way to go.

So, I created a rich text file, called test.rtf, and I am currently trying to display it in my webview. However, I am unsuccessful. I see only a blank white screen instead of the text I typed into the rtf file.

Can someone look at my code and point out where I went wrong with the implementation?

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
UIWebView * webView;
}
@end
```

Main file:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
@end
@implementation MainViewController

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Customization at initialization
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //Adding a webview to display richtext documents
    int webHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 150.0, 320.0, webHeight-150.0)];
    webView.dataDetectorTypes = NO;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webView setOpaque: NO];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Accessing richtext file
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
if (request) {
    // Additional configuration
}

//Adding the content of the webiew
[webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  NSLog(@"delegate called");
  // Do whatever you want here
  return YES;
  }
  @end

Comment: I created the rtf with Xcode; so, it is properly added to my application and shows up in the Project Navigator as expected.

Comment: Have you returned YES in your web view's delegate?

Comment: I did not create a webview delegate, nor did I link any existing file...

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView; Try this.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. But you know what? Don't worry about it. I'll accept your answer and try to figure out something else. :)

Comment: I don't worry about it. I want to help you. Can you put your project at some place and give me the link?

Comment: Thanks! :)
The entire code is pasted. But, here's the thing: I did try doing it with IB and it worked. It was the exact same code (I copy pasted it), except that in interface builder the webView was a weak, nonatomic IBOutlet. And it worked; I didn't even have to implement the delegate methods. I'll ask the programmar guys at work today and see what they say about this. I'll let you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your `UIWebView`'s delegate and return `YES`. [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
>
> Sent before a web view begins loading a frame.

So you should return `YES` for the first time to load your test.rtf file.

As you have updated your question. You need to set

```
webView.delegate = self;
//webView.delegate = appDelegate;    // not this line
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. I am a beginner; so, it may take some time, as working with delegates is a concept I do not yet fully understand...

Comment: You have the time. I've found this yesterday when I'm trying to write a demo to display some HTML files linked to each other. Keep in mind the delegate(also datasource for some UI elements).

Comment: Okay, so I added the following line to my app delegate ", UIWebViewDelegate" to also make it act as my webview delegate. Then added the viewcontroller.h in which I initialize the webview. then finally set the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method with a return YES, but it is still not working...

Comment: Update your question by pasting your code related to delegate. I need your code to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19711/discussion-between-gergely-kovacs-and-sunkehappy)